# How do I to prove that every solution from $\ddot y \ + \ \alpha \dot y \ + \ \beta y \ = \ 0$ tends to $0$ as t tends to $\infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that every solution from the differential equation $\ddot y \ + \ \alpha \dot y \ + \ \beta y \ = \ 0$ tends to $0$ as t tends to $\infty$. Then prove that if $\alpha $ or $ \beta$ are negative then there exists at least one not bounded solution in the positive. I have tried starting from the definition of the higher order equations then relate it to a limit but i haven't reached anything yet. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There must be restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, right? Otherwise, for $\alpha = -2$ and $\beta = 1$ we have the solution $y(t) = c_1 e^t + c_2te^t$. This does not tend to $0$ as $t$ gets large.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be positive, i apologize...

Comment: Given that $\alpha, \beta > 0$, what is the general shape of the solutions? (There are, depending on how you view these things, a couple of options.)

Comment: I do not see it, i just have this data..

Comment: Have you solved second order homogeneous linear differential equations with constant coefficients before? As in, do you know how @MattE. arrived at $y(t)$ above?

Comment: It comes down to the sign of the real part of $-\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2-4\beta}$; solutions go to zero at $+\infty$ if both are negative and a solution unbounded as $t \to \infty$ exists if at least one is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** the solutions of the characteristic equation $r^2 + \alpha r + \beta = 0$ tell you what the general solution to the differential equation look like. What can you say about that general solution (or equivalently, the solutions $r$ to the above polynomial equation) given that $\alpha, \beta > 0$?